# Where can I find a log of R session warnings?

Tags: r, session, logging, warnings, environment

One of my `R` scripts produced a message that there are some *warnings* during processing. However, since this is not an interactive session, I can't use `warnings()` to access the warnings. What is the **standard location**, if any, of the *most recent* R session's warnings log file, so that I could review them? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?warnings`:

> It is undocumented where last.warning is stored nor that it is
>   visible, and this is subject to change.

However, you can use the function `warnings` in your script and specify a file, where the last warnings should be saved.

```
warnings(file = "C:/Rwarnings.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's definitely good to know, but this particular script takes about an hour to run, so I'd prefer to find the location without code modification, if possible. Will certainly consider this approach in general. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: I suppose you are running your script via `R` or `Rscript`. If you are not running with the `--save` option (which is not on by default) I don't think you can recover any of the warnings. You will have to rerun after making changes as suggested.

Comment: @flodel: Yes, it's `Rscript`. And not only I'm not running the script with `--save` option, but I even explicitly specify `--no-save` option in the Makefile. I guess, I'm out of luck on this one. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @flodel By the way, is there a way to specify a log file location project-wide and/or site-wide? Via `warnings()`, `options()` or other?

Comment: Just read about `options(warn)`. I could just use this: "If warn is one, warnings are printed as they occur". And keep in mind the other choices for specific situations.

Comment: for site-wide, you could put @shadow's suggetsion above in your `Rprofile.site` file.

Comment: @flodel: Thank you! Do you mean `~ruser/.Rprofile`? I tried placing `warnings()` call per @shadow's advice, but it never produced a log file. I also tried placing `options(warn=1)` or `options(warn=2, error=recover)` in `~ruser/.Rprofile`, but also to no avail. What could be the reason for all this? Does the site-wide profile file gets read on every start of R session or on every `ruser` login? The only appearance of warning messages I see is when I interrupt R session via Ctrl-C, but it's not useful, as the info is incomplete both in terms of # of msgs and location of issues.

Comment: The doc is here: `?Startup`.